# How does DR/- work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, special-materials

For something like let's say an [Earth Elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/huge-earth-elemental/) that has a DR 5/-, what weapons can bypass that DR? 
I understand that all spells will still do full damage against the monster but I am particularly curious about magical weapons and weapons with special abilities and/or special materials. Because from my understanding if a monster has a DR that is bypassed by a magical weapon it is usually marked as DR 5/magic (and similarly in the case of a special material).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The – indicates that the damage reduction is not bypassed by *any* weapon. All weapon damage is reduced by that damage reduction. Damage reduction that is bypassed by magic weapons, weapons that deal bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage, weapons of a certain material, and/or weapons with a particular alignment, those all indicate that after the slash, and the – in this case indicates “none.”

Comment: +1.  You can pronounce it "DR/nuttin'."

Comment: I'd consider adding a note that there are abilities which cause attacks to ignore DR altogether, such as a Paladin's Smite Evil.

Answer (score 11):

As explained in the Universal Monster Rules in the Bestiary (copy found at [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Damage_Reduction_Ex_or_Su))

> When a damage reduction entry has a dash (—) after the slash, no weapon negates the damage reduction.

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers pretty much cover basic damage. The only way to "bypass" DR/- is by doing damage that DR does not reduce. A flaming weapon does its fire damage as normal. "[Damage Reduction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction) does not negate ... energy damage dealt along with an attack."